# Removing Elements in a StackPanel

Tags: google-apps-script

All,

I am trying to implement a StackPanel containing multiple sub-panels to collect user data.  Each subpanel (I have named them SwapRecordPanels) represents a line in a Google spreadsheet containing the data for two people who want to swap which days they will work.  The SwapRecordPanels contain a delete button.  On clicking the delete button, I would like the SwapRecordPanel to remove itself from the StackPanel.

However, I have found that when I attempt to remove an element from a StackPanel, the change does not register in the GUI.  As an attempt at the proof of the concept that I could delete elements in a StackPanel, I added an extra button titled "Click  Me".  As you can see in the code below, its handler attempts to remove an element from the StackPanel "LeftPanel."  However, when I click the button, the "LeftPanel" remains unchanged.  I'm wondering if there's some sort of refresh/repaint method to be called to update the GUI.  If not, could anyone offer any advice?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function myViewer() {
  var myapp = doGet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(myapp)
}

function doGet() {
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication();

  var LeftPanel = myapp.createStackPanel().setId("LeftPanel");
  var LeftScrollPanel = myapp.createScrollPanel(LeftPanel).setPixelSize(410,200)
  myapp.add(LeftScrollPanel)

  var SwapPane1 = SwapRecordPanel(LeftPanel);
  var SwapPane2 = SwapRecordPanel(LeftPanel);
  LeftPanel.add(SwapPane1,"Test 1 Header");
  LeftPanel.add(SwapPane2, "Test 2 Header");

  var myButton = myapp.createButton("Click    Me").addClickHandler(myapp.createServerHandler("ButtonClicker"));
  myapp.add(myButton);

  return myapp;
}

function ButtonClicker()
{
  Logger.log("I was clicked")
  var myapp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var LeftPanel = myapp.getElementById("LeftPanel");
  LeftPanel.remove(myapp.getElementById("panel1"));
}
```

Comment: Any news.?   Did you solved the problem. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to "return" the changes to the app from the handler function for the UI to update.

Simply add `return myapp;` at the end of the `ButtonClicker()` function.